# How to put validation for a model created by Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a database, added Entity Framework reverse engineering (in a Dll). I have created edit view, delete methods, everything is working fine.

I need to add validation. How to do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyDLL.Models
{
   public partial class ContactNumberTable
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
   }
}
```

This C# file is automatically created inside my dll project references model.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

First to start with this is what is called **`Data Annotations`**.To add validations to your `Model` you can add `Required[(ErrorMessage="")]` which is a `DataAnnotation Class` on any value you want to validate like below

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Validation message here")]//this is what sets the validation message
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Then in your `View` you have to do the below to get the Validation message showing when required:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "text-danger" })//this is the part the gets the validation error message
```

What this does is that it gets the error message for the value you put the Validation message on in your `View`. You can do this for any value you want Validated.

**EDIT**

There are several `Data Annotation` classes that you can use, you can read more here [Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs) and here [Entity Framework DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just extending the jamiedanq answer, If you only need to make the field as "REQUIRED" then put the

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="your message")]
```

on top of your properties.

If you need to validate some field from database (you would need to call a validation method on server from your view) then simply put,

```
[Remote("action name", "controller name", HttpMethod = "POST")]
```

on top of your fields.

It will call the action method by an AJAX call. You would need to add Jquery Validation in your views.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to decorate your properties with validation attribute.You can have muliple validation on single propery as shown below:-
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Mobile")]
 [RegularExpression(@"^([7-9][0-9]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Should be numbers only starting with 7,8 or 9")]
[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Mobile should be of Max Length 10 Characters only")]
public string Mobile{ get; set; }
```